# Laravel Eloquent - date attributes not being retrieved as Carbon objects

Tags: php, mysql, date, eloquent, laravel-5

I've got my `$dates` attribute on a Quota Eloquent model like this:

```
protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];
```

When retrieving data from the DB, those fields are not being set as Carbon instances, but strings instead. Same happens to `created_at` and `updated_at` properties.

Any ideas what could be happening? I'm using TIMESTAMPS fields on a MySQL DB and Laravel version is 5.2.

Comment: Are you creating `start` and `end` fields as `timestamps` or `datetimes`?

Comment: I'm using timestamps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code in your model:

```
public function getStartAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date);
}

public function getEndAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

The convention here is first write `get` then field name and `attribute`. They should write together in camel case. So, in your case the method name become `getStartAttribute` and `getEndAttribute`.

Comment: IMO, this is a kludgy workaround for something that should be fixed properly.

Comment: Ideally, it should work with setting $casts array but this seems to be broken for years now :(. This is the only workaround by using accessors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this if the table are in the User model (can be something else like News),

```
 $user = User::find($id);
 dump($user->start->format('Y-m-d');
```

This will dump the start column and format it to Y-m-d.

There is also a way to achieve this with te following, it will convert the `start` column for the database to a Carbon object and return it as `start_date` or `startDate` or `StartDate`:

```
public function getStartDateAttribute() {
    return Carbon::parse($this->start);
}
```

You can also look at the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, @smartrahat and @user2094178. I was wrong, the attributes are actually being retrieved as `Carbon` objects. I was confused, because I was getting an error when trying to use these accessors for formatting my dates:

```
public function getStartAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d/m/Y');
}

public function getEndAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

It seems at that point the values are already casted to strings (ie I can't use the `Carbon::format()` method). So I finally went with this approach:

```
public function getStartAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
}

public function getEndAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: There's an easier way. `$this->start->format(...)` in your accessors. I'd also suggest naming your accessors differently (like `formattedStart` or something), so you can still use the `$this->start` Carbon object in code.